# retrieve all tags with specific option value

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I edited my theme to allow me saving some extra data on `wp_options` table, to my tags using this code:

```
add_action ( 'edit_term', 'save_termmeta_tag');
   // save extra category extra fields callback function
function save_termmeta_tag( $term_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['Tag_meta'] ) ) {
        $t_id = $term_id;
        $tag_meta = get_option( "tag_$t_id");
        $tag_keys = array_keys($_POST['Tag_meta']);
            foreach ($tag_keys as $key){
            if (isset($_POST['Tag_meta'][$key])){
                $tag_meta[$key] = $_POST['Tag_meta'][$key];
            }
        }
        //save the option array
        update_option( "tag_$t_id", $tag_meta );
    }
}
```

Each group of these options is saved under the option name `tag_(tag ID here)`

Now I need to get all the tags with the option `$tag_meta['what_is_this']` »» (**product**).

How can I query with this?

Comment: I don't know if you can get those now with the default WP database queries, you might need to write your own JOIN for this. It would be way easier to do, if you stored this as _meta data_ on the tags themselves. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/12/how-to-use-term-meta-data-in-wordpress/ Then you could use `get_terms` with query parameters as described under https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/

Comment: @CBroe Thanks! In this case, how can I pass aal the option for each one of my tags to that table? Can you help?

Comment: You would use the meta data functions mentioned under https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/12/how-to-use-term-meta-data-in-wordpress/#meta-data-functions to store your data, and which parameters to use to then select them, see description of WP_Term_Query.